# "Sooner forgotten" Why is it not "soon forgotten"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, comparative-constructions

I came across a line when reading [Alice Munro's stories](https://books.google.ca/books?id=qNY05-5sgmAC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Another possible reason for his growling dislike has just occurred to me, and it’s odd that I didn’t think of it before. We were both flawed, obvious victims of physical misfortune. You would think such people would make common cause, but it could just as often happen that they don’t. Each may be reminded by the other of something **sooner forgotten**.

It appears to me the last sentence means:

> Each may be reminded by the other of something that would soon be forgotten/we'd soon forget.

A different sentence with *soon* would make sense to me, not the sentence as written. But what does "sooner" mean here in this sentence? Sooner than what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer by... rereading my own rephrased sentence of the original sentence, plus some research. When I tried to research the word **sooner** in the original sentence, I found it hard to do so, because some dictionaries show **sooner** to be a noun meaning an early Western settler or someone for Oklahoma (source: [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sooner)), and the original sentence doesn't make sense with this understanding.

After I rephrased the original sentence in my question, incidentally I found **would sooner** in Google searches, which means the same thing as *would rather*.

> Would rather and **would sooner** have the same meaning as would prefer. ([this site](http://www.tinyteflteacher.co.uk/learning-english/grammar/would-rather.html))
>
> *I’d sooner do something* is "used for saying what you would prefer to do" ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/i-d-sooner-do-something))

This has made the sentence make sense, with the help of my rewording. So

> Each may be reminded by the other of something that we'd soon forget. (my reworded version)

Means

> Each may be reminded by the other of something that we would rather forget.

And Munro's original sentence with *something* as its subject seems to be an exercise of poetic license, as it is basically saying

> Each may be reminded by the other of something that would rather be forgotten.

I don't think it's conventional or common to give **would rather/would sooner** an inanimate object without agency as a subject, so it appears Alice Munro is waxing poetic here.

Comment: Good research!  I was about to post almost exactly the same thing you found.

Comment: @stangdon I have learned so much from generous helpful users here, including you. Thought I'd do a bit more research after posting, and voila. I was also informed by the part of Andrew's answer to my yesterday's question on poetic license that taught me writers don't follow grammar...

Comment: @L.Moneta  for the most part, writers do follow grammar, but know when and how to deviate for artistic effect.   See for example the [poetry of E. E. Cummings](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poets/e-e-cummings), who throws both grammar and traditional formatting out the window.

Comment: Apt comparison to **rather**, but Munro isn't "waxing poetic" there at all.  To say that something is sooner forgotten is normal register.  **sooner** there = "more readily".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I still can't be sure that "sooner forgotten" is commonly used. I did find this line with **sooner forgotten**: _An injury is much sooner forgotten than an insult._ But it seems "sooner" here is used as the comparative of the adjective **soon**, rather than another form of the set phrase "would rather". Some sentences I later found with **would sooner** would not make sense if "sooner" is understood to be a comparative. So I didn't think _is much sooner forgotten than_ is relevant to the sentence at issue by Munro.

Comment: Compare "which one would just as soon forget", that is, would prefer to forget.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I actually wanted to ask about "just as soon". Your explanation makes sense and further clarifies it for me. There is "just as often" in the original text. Is it the same as "just as easily" and "just as soon"? Are there more similar _just as_ collocations?

Comment: "But they can also haunt us like reluctant ghosts, calling up insidious details of time and ourselves that are sooner forgotten." [i.e. which we would prefer to forget] https://www.nytimes.com/1991/10/20/books/bad-brother-on-his-doorstep.html

Comment: "just as easily forget" and "just as soon forget" can have different meanings. When something is just as easily forgotten, there's no special cause to remember it. But when something is "just as soon forgotten" there is reason to want to forget it, such as shame, embarrassment, ignominy, etc.

Comment: When dealing with a writer like Alice Munro, it is up to us to figure her out. It's just literary. And I would even say it's an idiom. Something is said to be sooner forgotten. "These are things one hopes are sooner forgotten." The implication is: forgotten sooner [than later]. That's why it's sooner.